# Receive many entities from DB per one query

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

For EF Core I have a collection of values, e.g. there are IDs of entities of my db's some table, and I want to receive multiple entities that are fit for these ID's.

It can be something like:

```
List<string> IDs { get; set; }
...
var listofEntities = new List<Foo>();
foreach(var id in IDs)
{
var result = context.Foos.Where(f => f.ID == id).Single();
listofEntities.Add(result);
}
```

However I think it's very slow approach. Can I get all needed entities per one query to DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `Contains`:

```
List<string> IDs { get; set; }
...
var listofEntities = context.Foos.Where(f => IDs.Contains(f.ID));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a join

```
var query = from foo in context.Foos
    join id in IDs on id equals foo.ID
    select foo;

return await query.ToListAsync();
```